# Arduino round to nearest 0.5

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having a double value for example: 34.26 or 11.92 or 2.51. It should be rounded to the nearest 0.5 so 1.34 -> 1.50 and 32.78 -> 33 and 21.09 -> 21.00

How do to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest not even using floats. 0.5 = 50, 1.34 = 134, 32.78=3278, should make the calculations faster/more efficient.

Comment: Also, let's say you have 134, you can do 134%50, which will return 34 and then you can check if it's above 24 (under = round to 0) and above 74 (under is round to 50) and else you round to 100.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to use float.
That being said. multiply by 2 and do a standard round.
Then divide back by 2.

For example:

```
1.34     *2 = 2.68
round(2.68) = 3
3        /2 = 1.5
```

and

```
32.78    *2 = 65.56
round(65.56)= 66
66       /2 = 33
```

Comment: The multiply by 2 is actually very clever I already felt like such a simple way should exist.

Comment: Commonly used for nearest 0.10 and 0.05 in cash registers, too (using 10, 20).

Answer (score 0):

I made a little algorithm from the first thing that popped into my mind.
I'm using integers, since I believe it works better as floats.

For example, you can represent euro's (with floating points) by expressing them in cents.

```
unsigned int roundToFifty(unsigned int nonRound){
    unsigned int rest = nonRound % 50;
    unsigned int fits = floor(nonRound / 50);
    unsigned int add = 0;
    if(rest >= 25){
        if(rest >= 75){
            add = 100
        }else{
            add = 50
        }
    }
    return fits*50+add
}
```

I actually think the algorithm is a tad weird and something simpler/more effective could also exist. It was just the first thing that popped into my mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
float i=1.5237475984328953;
#include "math.h"
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println(i,6);
 float price = i*1000;
 Serial.println(price,2);

 float roundNearest = roundf(i*1000) ; // x 100 for two decimal place
  roundNearest = roundNearest/1000;
 Serial.println(roundNearest,6);

 price = (roundNearest*1000);
 Serial.println(price,2);
 while(1){}
}
```

you u can use roundf()
like in this video [Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCcANoDHIdU)